# batchdelete causing NSMergeConflict coredata

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am only operating coredata on one thread. basically I have a messaging app and I am trying to delete messages in a batch... so this works.. but as soon as I start sending messages again... I get this error

this is what I use to delete messages:

```
 let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Mesages")
                        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "user.id = %@", friendID)
                        let batchDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
                        do {
                            try context.executeRequest(batchDeleteRequest)
                            context.refreshAllObjects()

                        } catch {}
```

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133020 "(null)" UserInfo={conflictList=(
>       "NSMergeConflict (0x610000264140) for NSManagedObject (0x6080000ae520) with objectID '0xd000000006640002 ' with oldVersion = 1 and newVersion =  and old object snapshot = {\n    fromID = 300147143696943;\n    isSender = 0;\n    status = \"\";\n    text = Ggg;\n    timestamp = \"2016-09-18 02:13:30 +0000\";\n    toID = \"\";\n    user = \"0xd000000000640000 \";\n}",
>       "NSMergeConflict (0x610000265ac0) for NSManagedObject (0x6000000adb60) with objectID '0xd000000006600002 ' with oldVersion = 2 and newVersion =  and old object snapshot = {\n    fromID = 300147143696943;\n    isSender = 0;\n    status = \"\";\n    text = Gg;\n    timestamp = \"2016-09-18 02:09:41 +0000\";\n    toID = \"\";\n    user = \"0xd000000000640000 \";\n}"
>   )}

I have no clue what's going on, can someone please help

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am facing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should set the mergePolicy of viewContext of persistentContainer（NSPersistentCloudKitContainer）before save(),write like this:

```
yourContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy
```

OR

```
yourContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
```